# How to fix a procedure to work for another functions?

Tags: algorithm

I have a procedure. It takes points and draws rectangles. The problem is to change the procedure to work not only with standarts functions. 
And the list of points must be :

```
ptsx = {0.067, 0.134, 0.201, 0.268, 0.335, 0.402, 0.469, 0.536, 0.603,
    0.67};
```

and the function : `f[x] = (-2*Exp[-x])/(Exp[x] - 2);`

So that  I have to call a procedure: `operation[ptsx, f[x], 0, 0.67]`

```
spxsin = {-1, -0.35, 0.3, 0.95, 1.6, 2.375, 3.15, 
       3.925, 4.7, 5.025, 5.35, 5.675, 6}; 
operation[value_, f_, a_, b_] := 
   Block[{data}, data = Table[{x, f[x]}, 
          {x, a, b, 0.1}]; Graphics[{Thick, Blue, 
          Line[data], Green, Table[
            Point[{value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}], 
            {i, 1, Length[value]}], Pink, Opacity[0.7], 
          Table[Rectangle[{value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}, 
              {value[[i + 1]], f[value[[i + 1]]]}], 
            {i, 1, Length[value] - 1}]}, Axes -> True]]
operation[spxsin, Sin, -1, 6]
```

This is a graph of this function `f[x] = (-2*Exp[-x])/(Exp[x] - 2);`:
[image]

Comment: Does `operation[ptsx, (-2*Exp[-#])/(Exp[#] - 2) &, 0, 0.67]` give what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to define `f` with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), then it could be used in the same way as a built-in function and all will be well.

```
f[x_] := (-2*Exp[-x])/(Exp[x] - 2)
```

I have made some minor changes to `operation` to get, what to my eye, is better visibility of the plotted graphics elements.

```
operation[value_, f_, a_, b_, aspect_] :=
  Block[{data},
    data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, a, b, 0.1}];
    Graphics[
      {Thick, Lighter[Blue], Line[data],
       Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
         Table[Point[{value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}], {i, 1, Length[value]}],
       Pink, Opacity[0.7], 
         Table[
           Rectangle[
             {value[[i]], f[value[[i]]]}, 
             {value[[i + 1]], f[value[[i + 1]]]}], 
           {i, 1, Length[value] - 1}]},
   AspectRatio -> aspect, 
   Axes -> True]]

operation[spxsin, f, -1, 6, .6]
```

[image: plot]